# Best mechanism for high-performance push to .net clients from Java EE server

Tags: .net, sockets, jakarta-ee, jboss

We've got a system that will consist of a Java EE server (JBoss) that needs to periodically push data to .Net Windows apps (thick clients).  Performance is critical - the data will be high-volume and need to be updated by the second.  All clients will be on the local LAN.

Of course doing this at the socket level is the most natural solution.  But who wants to work at the socket level in 2013?

JMS is out as, again, this is Windows.

The clients will request data from the service via a RESTful interface, incidentally.  But that won't work for the push.

If the clients were browsers we'd be doing Web Sockets so perhaps raw TCP is not a bad idea.  It's not like it would be difficult.  However, I would like to explore all possibilities, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: JMS works perfectly fine in windows

Comment: Even in a C# application?

Comment: Perhaps NMS: http://blog.koller.it/2010/02/17/communication-between-c-net-and-java-via-activemq-messaging-part-1/

Comment: Check out [CometD](http://cometd.org)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a C# application from JBoss, you still can use message queues, just pick one that has bindings for both C# and Java (not necessarily JMS) and then configure the C# app to periodically read the queues, or to be notified when a message arrives, and then the JBoss server will push messages in queues as well